# STM32 libraries for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, stm32, microcontroller

Can you use the CMSIS, HAL, TM libraries for STM32F407 discovery board with  eclipse, without STM32Cube? According to this link http://www.carminenoviello.com/en/2015/06/04/stm32-applications-eclipse-gcc-stcube/ you can do it with eclipse & STM32Cube. But I wonder if you can do just same thing without the STM32Cube. Since I'm using OS X, it is impossible to install the STM32Cube, but in order to use the GPIO library I need to use CMSIS, HAL, TM libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to used the older "Standard Peripheral Driver" model - which was a just a distributed set of driver files specific to the chip.  These libraries are no longer supported and are replaced by STM32Cube which generates equivalent code - but with better support for hardware abstraction however they are still very useable.
Search "STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver" to locate the libraries (which include the standard peripheral drivers and CMSIS).

Comment: SPL is not supported by STM for years now, it is outdated and it should not be used in any new projects. This answer is wrong. SPL was replaced by the HAL, and it used to exactly the same job. Do not use SPL.

Answer (score 2):

**You can download the libraries as a separate zip file**

http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243

just unpack it and import whatever you need from it into your project. You can take an example project which is closest to your needs, and start developing your application from that. That's what I did in Linux.

There is the STM32Cube**MX**, which is the installable program you're referring to, and there are STM32CubeF4, STM32CubeL0, etc, which are the firmware package for the different controller families.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I could use the Cube libraries.

Answer (score 1):

CubeMX now officially supports Mac and Linux. However here is an old post how to run it manually http://www.carminenoviello.com/2015/09/09/running-stm32cubemx-macos-finally/.

Regarding the HAL and SPL I'll add that there are really nice libraries in libopencm3 which are developed by community and are not so "buggy" as HAL or SPL.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting instruction. You can install the STM32CubeMX on OS X. http://www.stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=267

Answer (score 0):

There is an Eclipse based IDE by OpenSTM32 community called SW4STM32. Available at [OpenSTM32 community's site](http://www.openstm32.org/HomePage). System Workbench for STM32 installer has been released on the following platforms:

- Microsoft Windows Vista and newer (32 bits or 64 bits)
- Linux (32 bits or 64 bits)
- Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite and newer + Xcode 7
- Java SE JRE 7 or newer

When creating a project you can choose which library you want want to use, SPL, HAL or baremetal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

STM32CubeMX is a initialization code generator. It definitely eases development, but you can write you code completely from the beginning.

STM32CubeMX uses HAL as its Library. You can download the HAL and Include the files that you need and write down the code from scratch. You just need to be aware of the APIs, which are documented in UM1725 Application Note.

But, now STM32CubeMX is also available for Linux and Mac.